# Performance concerns with multiple currencies and regions

Tags: mysql

I have a set of hourly data in 10+ currencies, and 21 regions.

I insert 1 row per currency, per region, per hour. This means I get 24 hours * 10 currencies * 21 regions = 5040 rows of data per day.

I'm looking at expanding to more currencies and more regions, and it sounds like this would quickly become a performance/space issue.

**How I currently store data in 10 currencies and 21 regions:**

My table:

```
id, val, currency_id, region_id, val_date
```

First hour, region 1, currencies 1-10:

```
1, 145.24, 1, 1, '2022-14-06 00:00:00'
2, 134.11, 2, 1, '2022-14-06 00:00:00'
...
10, 136.61, 10, 1, '2022-14-06 00:00:00'
```

Second hour, region 1, currencies 1-10:

```
11, 142.54, 1, 1, '2022-14-06 01:00:00'
12, 131.21, 2, 1, '2022-14-06 01:00:00'
...
20, 133.35, 10, 1, '2022-14-06 01:00:00'
```

First hour, region 2, currencies 1-10:

```
241, 125.22, 1, 2, '2022-14-06 00:00:00'
242, 118.15, 2, 2, '2022-14-06 00:00:00'
...
250, 120.79, 10, 2, '2022-14-06 00:00:00'
```

My concern is mostly related to all these duplicated dates.

Here's some ideas I've had:

- Create a separate `dates` table, and use `JOIN` with `date_id`
- Hard code the currencies as columns (`eur_val`, `usd_val`, `cad_val`, ...)
- Stick with what I currently have

What would be the optimal way to solve this?

Comment: Maybe you could save the historical data in a diffrent table

Comment: Partitioning of the tables, maybe by month ? For the date, if you use a date-time field, it's stored as a numeric value, like your date_id, so no use, keep the date.

Comment: @Blag Interesting, I will give it a look. Considering I don't use the minutes and hours from DATETIME, would it be better if I used a single column for DATE and then a separate TINYINT column for hour, possibly?

Comment: You are adding 150k rows a month. In today's databases that is nothing. I wouldn't worry about performance or space even if you had 10 times more data per month. Your structure is good.

Comment: Tbh, your data remind me of some fact table of a DWH, depending on how you use it, partitioning could definitely be a good idea, but be careful, that mean only request that specify the date in a WHERE will be speed up, the other may by a bit slower.
For the date, I'll not bother, just use a UTC date-time field (and keep the local offset in your Region table).

Comment: @TheImpaler it depend of the DB and the use. A small mySql on a shared hosting, with some page view / heavy query without caching may start to feel slow past 1M rows. On the other side, an Oracle / Postgres on a dedicated server can handle a thousand time more given a bit of indexing.

Comment: "solve this" Solve what? What is the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question? [ask] [Help] [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [mre] PS Why is this tagged database-normalization?

Answer (score 0):

> quickly become a performance/space issue

Not.

5K rows/day = 2M rows/year -- That's "medium-sized" as database tables go.

> id, val, currency_id, region_id, val_date

What are the datatypes?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)  I would guess:

INT, DECIMAL(8,2), TINYINT, TINYINT, DATETIME
4 + 4 + 1 + 1 + 5 bytes, plus a lot of overhead -- maybe 60 bytes per row.  So the table might be 100MB/year.  How big is your disk?

DATE=3, TINYINT=1, DATETIME=5 -- But due to overhead and clumsiness, I suggest that splitting the datatime would make speed, space, and code all worse.

The next issue is to ask about INDEXes.  But to do that, we need to see the SELECTs that you will perform.

Do not use Partitioning unless you plan on periodically deleting "old" data.